# Finding latest market price of market portfolio according to No Arbitrage

Tags: modern-portfolio-theory, capm, sharpe-ratio, no-arbitrage-theory

In Excel, I have the monthly stock price data for the past few years for Asset A and Asset B. I have calculated the monthly returns, mean returns, variances, and standard deviations for both stocks as well as the covariance and correlation.

Then I calculated the weighted portfolios of Asset A and Asset B calculating the return and standard deviation for each portfolio, this let me draw the mean-variance frontier (MVF).

Then I solved the optimisation problem to find the smallest variance portfolio.

Then I found the portfolio with the highest Sharpe Ratio. I used a short-term government bond as a risk-free asset. Then I drew a new efficient frontier.

I am now tasked with: finding the market price of mkt portfolio according to No Arbitrage condition. How do I do this?

Answer (score 3):

To find the current market price of the market portfolio, you need to multiply the current/latest market price of each asset by its respective weight in the tangent portfolio and then sum them up. This will give you the market price of the market portfolio (tangent portfolio) according to the No Arbitrage condition.